# DotNetOpenAuth Nuget package installation failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, installation, nuget, dotnetopenauth

I just tried to install DoNetOpenAuth Nuget package and it failed for an ASP.net MVC 4 application:

```
PM> Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth
Attempting to resolve dependency 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.UI (= 4.3.2.13293)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core.UI (= 4.3.2.13293)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core.UI (= 4.3.2.13293)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'DotNetOpenAuth.Core (= 4.3.2.13293)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.1.3)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'DotNetOpenAuth.Mvc (= 4.3.2.13293)'.
Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'DotNetOpenAuth.Mvc (= 4.3.2.13293)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I downloaded the binaries from DonetOpenAuth.net and the bin library for .net 4.5 had just one DLL -- DotNetOpenAuth.dll. It didn't have the other DLLs such as DotNetOpenAuth.Core, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty etc.

TIA for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth -version 4.3.3.13295

Comment: After installing this version, I'm getting a compilation error because VS cannot find the namespace DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.

Comment: I installed DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet and I'm in business again. Sorry for the false call.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - went back a version and it installed fine:

Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth -version 4.3.1.13153

Answer (score 0):

This was [bug #309](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/309). Just fixed. Version 4.3.3 has the fix.